# Flex: is it possible to style a Flex app without going insane?

Tags: apache-flex

Are there any libraries out there which will help me style a Flex application without going insane?

For example, is there any "accepted" way to set an element's size/position without hard-coding it into each element?

Answer (score 2):

The width, height and position of elements are not styles, they are properties. Unfortunately they can't be set via a stylesheet.

What you could do is extend one of the Container classes and override the childrenCreated() method, access the elements in the "children" Array and set the values you want.

Comment: Hrm, yea... I've learned that Flex doesn't consider positioning information "style"... Oh well. I guess this is just "something to live with"?

Comment: Due to the nature of the UIComponent lifecycle (which uses methods such as measure() and updateDisplayList() to dynamically determine size / positioning ) it's not something that can easily be solved in the way you suggest. If you have a ton of screens that need to be laid out in a consistent manner, I really would recommend creating a custom Container to do this for you. Learning the intricacies of the UIComponent lifecycle will put you in the top 5-10% of Flex developers; most don't understand it at all.

Comment: I should add that there are some styles that can affect the positioning of child elements such as the horizontal/verticalGap and top/bottom/let/rightPadding styles of the Box component. If you look at the source for BoxLayout you'll see how these are used to control positioning of children. Writing a custom component that makes use of similar layout styles might help you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use VBox and HBox components that layout the children either vertically or horizontally.  I would avoid nesting this too much because it will affect your applications performance.

Comment: Let's say I want to do this: <VBox><Label A> <Label B> <Label C></VBox>.  Without individually setting the width property on each of those labels there is no way (without dropping into ActionScript) to say "make all the labels below that VBox have a width of 100".

Comment: I gotcha...you can do what brd6644 says below or just extend the label class and override the width so its 100% or the desired width.

Comment: Well, yes, I could do it that way... But I was hoping for something cleaner :( Or maybe I just need to adjust my definition of "clean"...